# Passing click function to child component got undefined in angular

Tags: angular

let say I have `Button` component like bellow

button.component.ts

```js
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrl: './button.component.scss'
})
export class ButtonComponent {
  @Input() type?: string
  @Input() click?: () => any
}
```

button.component.html

```html
<button (click)="click?.()" [type]="type || 'submit'" class="button">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</button>
```

Then I use the button in another component

home.component.ts

```js
import { CommonModule, } from '@angular/common'
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { FormBuilder, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import { ButtonComponent } from '../shared/button/button.component'
import { ISignIn } from './home.interface'
import { HomeService } from './home.service'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ButtonComponent, ReactiveFormsModule],
  providers: [HomeService],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrl: './home.component.scss'
})
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
  form = this.formBuilder.group<ISignIn>({
    email: '',
    password: ''
  })

  signIn() {
    console.log(this.formBuilder) // got undefined

    const value = this.form.value
    console.log(value)

  }
}
```

home.component.html

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" />
    <app-button [click]="signIn">Login</app-button>
  </form>
```

Comment: This is not the correct way, you need to use @Output decorator and then emit the event from button. Check this https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-parent-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to understand that at runtime, your function `signIn` looses its context. When the app runs in the browser, the `this` context will be lost, since in that situation, the global context takes place. In order to fix this, you will have to pass into your child component `signIn.bind(this)`, not only `signIn`.

A more Angular approach would be:

- define an @Output property inside your child component (which could be subtype of `Observable` or simply an `EventEmitter<T>`)
- this property must `emit` a value every time you want your parent component to react to that event